# sqoop can't convert long to timestamp when export data from HDFS to oracle

Tags: oracle, mapreduce, export, sqoop

I have a csv file in hdfs with this format:

```
000000131,2020-07-22,0.0,"","",1595332359218,khf987ksdfi34
000000112,2020-07-22,0.0,"","",1595442610265,khf987ksdfi34
000000150,2020-07-22,0.0,"","",1595442610438,khf987ksdfi34
```

I want to export this file to oracle using sqoop like this:

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=oracledb)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=stgdb)))" --table CORE_ETL.DEPOSIT_TURNOVER --username xxxx --password xxxx --export-dir /tmp/merged_deposit_turnover/ --input-fields-terminated-by "," --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --map-column-java DATE=java.sql.Date,INSERT_TS=java.sql.Timestamp
```

but the process ended with this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '1595332359218' at 
CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.__loadFromFields(CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.java:546) at 
CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.parse(CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.java:431) at   
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:88) ... 10 more Caused 
by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143) at 
CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.__loadFromFields(CORE_ETL_DEPOSIT_TURNOVER.java:529) ... 12 more
```

I wonder there is a way without changing the format of data in HDFS I can export this file to oracle.

also oracle schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per sqoop official documentation:
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_export_date_and_timestamp_data_types_into_oracle

while exporting data from hdfs, the Sqoop export command will fail if the data is not in the required format and the required format for the timestamp is : yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff . So you will have to format the timestamps in your files to conform to the aforementioned format to export properly to Oracle.

Comment: thank you. yes I read that! but I said maybe someone has a creative way to solve this issue